# Error: type is ‘unsigned int’ where ‘long unsigned int’ is expected in a call to built-in function

Tags: c

Building a module of a large code is producing the following output:

```
In file included from main.c:2:
main.c: In function ‘allocate’:
defs.h:101:33: warning: ‘calloc’ argument 1 type is ‘unsigned int’ where ‘long unsigned int’ is expected in a call to built-in function declared without prototype [-Wbuiltin-declaration-mismatch]
```

Here, the critical content of defs.h seems to be

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>


/*  machine-dependent definitions           */
/*  the following definitions are for the Tahoe     */
/*  they might have to be changed for other machines    */

/*  MAXCHAR is the largest unsigned character value */
/*  MAXSHORT is the largest value of a C short      */
/*  MINSHORT is the most negative value of a C short    */
/*  MAXTABLE is the maximum table size          */
/*  BITS_PER_WORD is the number of bits in a C unsigned */
/*  WORDSIZE computes the number of words needed to */
/*  store n bits                    */
/*  BIT returns the value of the n-th bit starting  */
/*  from r (0-indexed)              */
/*  SETBIT sets the n-th bit starting from r        */

    #define MAXCHAR     255
    #define MAXSHORT    32767
    #define MINSHORT    -32768
    #define MAXTABLE    32500
    #define BITS_PER_WORD   32
    #define WORDSIZE(n) (((n)+(BITS_PER_WORD-1))/BITS_PER_WORD)
    #define BIT(r, n)   ((((r)[(n)>>5])>>((n)&31))&1)
    #define SETBIT(r, n)    ((r)[(n)>>5]|=((unsigned)1<<((n)&31)))
    ...

    /*  storage allocation macros  */
    
    #define CALLOC(k,n) (calloc((unsigned)(k),(unsigned)(n)))
    #define FREE(x)     (free((char*)(x)))
    #define MALLOC(n)   (malloc((unsigned)(n)))
    #define NEW(t)      ((t*)allocate(sizeof(t)))
    #define NEW2(n,t)   ((t*)allocate((unsigned)((n)*sizeof(t))))
    #define REALLOC(p,n)    (realloc((char*)(p),(unsigned)(n)))
    
    ...
```

My C is pretty rusty and I know that `unsigned` and `unsigned long` are not the same but I'm unsure what is triggering the error. The system (AArch64) is running on CentOS 8 and the compiler is GCC-11. Thanks.

Comment: You need to `#include <stdlib.h>` for the proper prototype of `calloc()` (and `malloc()` and `realloc()` and `free()`).

Comment: Where in the code shown do you get the error? Please try to show us a proper [mre].

Comment: And why all the `(unsigned)` casts? The standard allocation functions uses a `size_t` values for the size, and if you wrap them then you should too.

Comment: Also... don't `calloc()` inside `.h` files.

Comment: Not my code. It's a very long one, which is compiling but causing errors when running it, and I'm just trying to fix the memory leaks.

Comment: Which line is `defs.h:101`?

Comment: Line 101 is #define CALLOC (k,n) ..

Comment: Is there a `#include <stdlib.h>` within defs.h itself or within main.c before the `#include "defs.h"`?

Comment: I included the top portion of defs.h. It has stdio but not stdlib. main.c doesn't have anything like that, it declares include <signal.h> & #include "defs.h".

Comment: Try to add `#include <stdlib.h>` to your header file.

Comment: That seems to have gotten rid of the error. Not sure why, but I'll have to read about it. Thanks.

Comment: As you hopefully know, all functions you call must be *declared* before you actually call them. The memory functions are declared in the `<stdlib.h>` header file. And to be brutally honest, all decent books, tutorials and classes should have mentioned this.

Comment: You're 100% right and I'm aware of variable declaration. As I mentioned, C is not my programming language (that explains my forgetfulness about the content of stdlib) and the app was written by some other group, so I have no clue why they didn't include stdlib.h but I'll check if it's missing anywhere else. Thanks.

Comment: Implicit declaration of a function by a call to an undeclared function (`calloc` in this case) is a feature that was removed in C99.

Comment: Those `malloc`, `calloc` and `realloc` calls should be taking `size_t` arguments - that's a type that varies between builds, even on the same compiler. It's also what the type was invented for. It can be `unsigned`, `unsigned long` or even `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Adrian. Sorry but I'm not sure if I'm able to implement your suggestion correctly. Which would be the right syntax for line 101? Would it be `#define CALLOC(k,n) (calloc(sizeof(unsigned)(k),sizeof(unsigned)(n)))` or something else?

Comment: No. Just use `size_t` *in place of* `unsigned`: `#define CALLOC(k,n) (calloc((size_t)(k),(size_t)(n)))`. See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t).

Comment: OK. That looks much better than mine. Let me try.

Comment: At the end, I came up with `#define CALLOC(k,n) (calloc((size_t)(k),(size_t)(n)))` && `#define FREE(x)     (free((char*)(x)))` && `#define MALLOC(n)   (malloc((size_t)(n)))` && `#define NEW(t)      ((t*)allocate(sizeof(t)))` && `#define NEW2(n,t)   ((t*)allocate((size_t)((n)*sizeof(t))))` && `#define REALLOC(p,n)    (realloc((char*)(p),(size_t)(n)))`. This seems correct but the compilation is still showing memory leak problems and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @afernandezody All the casts in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69226073/error-type-is-unsigned-int-where-long-unsigned-int-is-expected-in-a-call-to#comment122358849_69226073) should be removed.  They quiet useful warnings of bad code.